# Qt: How to select the window frame in a mouseMoveEvent?

Tags: qt

I know this can be done with a QSizeGrip, but it looks clunky, so I’d prefer to use the usual window edges. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "select the window frame"?

Comment: @Nikos: I'm trying to implement my own click-drag resizing method, so I need to detect clicks that fall on edges of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window decorations ("borders") are handled by the window manager (which is part of the operating system's desktop,) not by the application itself. You cannot receive mouse events for them. A way around that is to disable the borders completely, and implement your own. This is quite a bit of work and will probably annoy users depending on the nature of your application (something like WinAmp for example can get away with it; Google Chrome on the other hand is doing it too, but many users don't like it.)

Comment: Bad news for me, but at least I know not to waste my time with it.